# How to run an activation function when plugin is network activated on multisite?

Tags: multisite, activation

I'm trying to make my plugin multisite compatible. I'm using the `register_activation_hook()` function to register my `my_activate()` function to run when the plugin is activated. This works well on a single-site install.

```
function my_activate() {
    // Do some things.
}
register_activation_hook( __FILE__, 'my_activate' );
```

The problem is, `my_activate()` doesn't run for each site when my plugin is 'network activated'. Also, it doesn't run when new sites are created on the network.

How can I get my activation routine to **a)** run when my plugin is network activated for all sites in the network and **b)** run when a new site is created on the multisite network?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Your callback function *should* run when your plugin is network activated or activated for a single site. Either way, it should be working.

However, if you intend for the code contained within your callback to be ran for each blog in your network, then be aware that this will not happen out of the box, instead, the code within your callback will in the primary blog context.

#### If your code needs to run on each blog upon Network Activation:

```
function my_plugin_activate($network_wide) {

    if ( is_multisite() && $network_wide ) { 

        foreach (get_sites(['fields'=>'ids']) as $blog_id) {
            switch_to_blog($blog_id);
            //do your specific thing here...
            restore_current_blog();
        } 

    } else {
        //run in single site context
    }

}

register_activation_hook( __FILE__, 'my_plugin_activate' );
```

#### If your code needs to run when a new blog is created:

```
function my_plugin_new_blog($blog_id) {

    //replace with your base plugin path E.g. dirname/filename.php
    if ( is_plugin_active_for_network( 'my-plugin-name-dir/my-plugin-name.php' ) ) {
        switch_to_blog($blog_id);
        //do your specific thing here...
        restore_current_blog();
    } 

}

add_action('wpmu_new_blog', 'my_plugin_new_blog');
```

### Additionally:

For those reading who want similar functionality but for all plugins that get network activated *(not just the one you control, if at all applicable)*, then you may wish to look at: https://wordpress.org/plugins/proper-network-activation/ which will ensure that each plugin in your multisite network in which is network activated, has both its `register_activation_hook` and `register_deactivation_hook` run in each blog context.

Comment: thanks for the solution, much appreciated! Regarding your first sentence, I've updated my question's wording slightly.

Comment: I'm wondering how is `$network_wide` passed to `my_plugin_activate()`?

Comment: @henrywright `register_activation_hook` is just a wrapper around `add_action('activate_' . $file, $function)` which in itself fires upon, `do_action( 'activate_' . $plugin, $network_wide )` of which you can see the variable `$network_wide` and its value state, one of either `true` or `false` is always passed as an argument to the callback. Hence, you have access to this argument in your `register_activation_hook` and `register_deactivation_hook` wrappers. For more information see `activate_plugin` function within `wp-admin/includes/plugin.php`. Hope that helps.

Comment: Appreciate the explanation, and thanks again for your answer :)

Comment: I'm not sure is it outdated answer but when I try to `var_dump($network_wide)` it show me empty string `''` in WordPress 4.9.1.

Comment: I think you should update your answer: WP4.6 introduced get_sites() function so: 
foreach (get_sites() as $site) {
            switch_to_blog($site->blog_id);
            //do your specific thing here...
            restore_current_blog();
        }

Comment: @ErenorPaz `restore_current_blog` needs to be in the `foreach` loop, because if you put it outside, then iterate (switch over) to 10 blogs for example, the last call to `restore_current_blog` will restore the last blog you switched to and NOT the original blog you started at (presumably your main site). https://codex.wordpress.org/WPMU_Functions/restore_current_blog

Comment: @ErenorPaz so basically current code is doing this: (pseudo example) Assuming starting at `Blog 1 → switch_to_blog 2 | do logic | → go back to blog 1 → switch_to_blog 3 | do logic | → go back to blog 1`... and so on. Alternatively, outside of `foreach` loop you could call, `switch_to_blog(1)` twice one after the other... Then if anyone accidentally calls `restore_current_blog` they will still remain in the right context.

Comment: @userabuser You are right! I'm going to delete my comment, to avoid anyone using that method

Comment: @ErenorPaz no need to delete the comment, doing so makes the chat history confusing to read for people. There's nothing wrong giving an opinion even if it may not be correct. No one is going on hate on you for that, we are community here to help, discuss, learn and gain perspective. Anyway all good...